# Avoid exception when there is no integer number filled in the edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm working with Android app, I have 5 edit text, and 1 button to sum the integer number from those edit text. Sometime user can let several edit text blanks. The problem is when the user let it blank, the exception will arise and I don't have any idea to handle it. These are my code

```
try
    {
        if (qty1 != null)
        {
            int jml1 = Integer.parseInt(qty1.getText().toString());
            item1 = hrg1 * jml1;
        }
        else 
        {
            qty1.setText("0");
        }
        if (qty2 != null)
        {
            int jml2 = Integer.parseInt(qty2.getText().toString());
            item2 = hrg2 * jml2;
        }
        else 
        {
            qty2.setText("0");
        }
        if (qty3 != null)
        {
            int jml3 = Integer.parseInt(qty3.getText().toString());
            item3 = hrg3 * jml3;
        }
        else 
        {
            qty3.setText("0");
        }
        if (qty4 != null)
        {
            int jml4 = Integer.parseInt(qty4.getText().toString());
            item4 = hrg4 * jml4;
        }
        else 
        {
            qty4.setText("0");
        }
        if (qty5 != null)
        {
            int jml5 = Integer.parseInt(qty5.getText().toString());
            item5 = hrg5 * jml5;
        }
        else 
        {
            qty5.setText("0");
        }
int hasil = item1 + item2 + item3 + item4 + item5;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Berhasil", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        total.setText(String.valueOf(hasil));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Quantity can't be empty. Please type item quantity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

I have try to put condition with if but it doesn't help much. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
if (qty1.getText().toString() != null && !(qty1.getText().toString().equals("")))
        {
            int jml1 = Integer.parseInt(qty1.getText().toString());
            item1 = hrg1 * jml1;
        }
```

instead of,

```
if (qty1 != null)
        {
            int jml1 = Integer.parseInt(qty1.getText().toString());
            item1 = hrg1 * jml1;
        }
```

This condition if `(qty1 != null)` checks if your editText is null but it doesn't check the data contained in it.

Repeat the same for all the other editText values.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. But can you tell what is exclamation sign in front of this code `!(qty1.getText().toString().equals(""))` ??

Comment: it is equivalent to "not". which simply means "if this is not the condition" then do the operation, if not skip it up.

Answer (score 1):

put this condition

```
String s1= qty5.getText().toString().trim();

if(TextUtils.isEmpty(s1)) ///// isEmpty() <-----
{
 // error message
}
else
{
 // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `qty1` is yout edittext then you need to get the string from your edittext to check whether it is `null` or not.

So Change your all edittexts code as like this

```
    if (qty1.getText().toString() != null && qty1.getText().toString().equals(""))
    {
        int jml1 = Integer.parseInt(qty1.getText().toString());
        item1 = hrg1 * jml1;
    }
    else 
    {
        qty1.setText("0");
    }
```